# Doing DSPSMTF to display a stmf on browser but it all junk and it is downlading the file instead of displaying it. Also any idea about CONTTYPES file?

Tags: cgi, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am using CGI DSPSTMF command to display stmf file on web browser. I am copying a spool file to a stmf file using CPYSPLF *STMF option. Once copied i am passing IFS location to DSPSTMF command but it is going to download automatically and when i open the download file i am getting all Junk data any idea why?
Also, i noticed it is using CONTTYPES file in CGILIB and on my server it is empty. What should be the values in it and what should i do show correct data instead of junk. I tried to use different methods to copy the file to IFS like used cpytostmf instead of cpysplf but on IFS file looks correct not the download version.

Answer (score 1):

What CCSID is the resulting stream file tagged with?
use `WRKLNK` and option `8=Display attributes`

If 65535, that tells the system the data is binary and it won't try to translate the EBCDIC to ASCII.

The correct fix is to properly configure your IBM i so that the stream file is tagged with it's correct CCSID.

Do a `WRKSYSVAL QCCSID` ... if your system is still set to 65535, that's the start of your problem.  But this isn't programming related, you can try posting to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) but you might get better responses on the [Midrange mailing list](https://lists.midrange.com/mailman/listinfo/midrange-l)

Comment: I have taken care of CCSID and it is working now.. tough i am getting another error. Once DSPSTMF runs and when i try to reload the HTML, it still holds back the input field values from HTML as well as button values..

Comment: You should create a new question